# opencv trackbar can not fully display title

Tags: c++, opencv

I created a trackbar using the code below

```
createTrackbar("adjust hessian:", "lena", hessian, 2000, callback,&img_1);
```

And the problem is, the string "adjust hessian" can not be fully display, but display like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wC4oH.png)

The letters in the middle is skipped and I want to know why.
Best regard.